# Quotation mark in column name - Invalid column name

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server 2017 and having a problem with the double quotation marks in columns' names

The query I used is like this:

```
insert into torque_value.value_table("ID","value","timestamp") values ('111','1111',convert(datetime,'2017-12-12T00:34:00.000'))
```

which worked well in SQL Server management studio but did not work at all in `sqlcmd` and it returned error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server USER\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
Invalid column name 'ID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server USER\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
Invalid column name 'value'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server USER\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
Invalid column name 'timestamp'.
```

Is the syntax in the sqlcmd different from in SSMS ? How should I handle this kind of error ?

Comment: Use brackets `[]` to escape column and table names in SQL Server

Comment: You don't need to use quotation marks of any type around column names sl long as they are consistent with the regular identifiers rules. And you **should not** use reserved words for column names.

Comment: @juergend I tried that but it didn't not help in `sqlcmd`

Comment: @SMor I know that we don't need to use quotation marks but the situation is we have another device generating query which always have double quotation marks in the columns' name. I didn't think about the reserved words problem, I will soon check it